# replacing values of a dataframe column using values of a list and list name in R

Tags: r, list, data-cleaning

I would like to replace Values inside of a column with a list name conditional upon the values being inside the list values:

```
df <- data.frame(Activity = c("Checking emails", "Playing games", "Reading", "Watching TV", 
                         "Watching YouTube", "Watching TV", "Relaxing", "Getting ready", 
                         "Working/ studying", "Relaxing"))

mylist <-list(Tech_activity = c("Browsing social media", "Checking emails", 
"Video calling", "On my computer/ PC", "Watching YouTube", "Browsing the internet", 
"On my phone", "Watching TV"), Socialising = c("Spending time with friends", 
"Chatting/ talking/ having a conversation", "Spending time with family"
), Work = "Working/ studying", Transport = c("Travelling", "Walking", 
"Driving"), Household = c("Housework", "Cooking"), Leisure = c("Exercising/ Working out", 
"Getting ready", "Exercising/ working out", "Hobbies eg knitting", 
"Playing games", "Shopping", "Eating", "Listening to music", 
"Reading", "Smoking", "Playing with pets", "Personal caring", 
"Personal care", "Nothing", "Relaxing", "Waiting"))
```

So if the data frame value is in the values of an element in the list, then replace the df with that element name, if not skip that element and check the next element of the list and so on. (Please excuse the double for-loop).

```
for (i in df$Activity){
  for (j in mylist){
    if (i %in% mylist[j]){
      i <- names(mylist[j])
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `mylist` as dataframe and then `merge` it with `df`.

```
merge(df, stack(mylist), by.x = 'Activity', by.y = 'values')
```

---

A `tidyverse` way would be :

```
library(tidyverse)

enframe(mylist) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  right_join(df, by = c('value' = 'Activity'))

#   name          value            
#   <chr>         <chr>            
# 1 Tech_activity Checking emails  
# 2 Tech_activity Watching YouTube 
# 3 Tech_activity Watching TV      
# 4 Tech_activity Watching TV      
# 5 Work          Working/ studying
# 6 Leisure       Getting ready    
# 7 Leisure       Playing games    
# 8 Leisure       Reading          
# 9 Leisure       Relaxing         
#10 Leisure       Relaxing
```

Comment: Wow, very helpful thank you. That was a perspective I didn't have

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```r
matches <- unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) which(df$Activity %in% x)))
df$Activity[matches] <- gsub("\\d+$", "", names(matches))

df
#>         Activity
#> 1  Tech_activity
#> 2        Leisure
#> 3        Leisure
#> 4  Tech_activity
#> 5  Tech_activity
#> 6  Tech_activity
#> 7        Leisure
#> 8        Leisure
#> 9           Work
#> 10       Leisure
```

Comment: I tried to accept both answers as they are correct and great but it will only let me do one

Comment: @ElliotM no problem. Choose the one that best answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
enframe(mylist, value = 'Activity') %>%
      unnest(c(Activity)) %>%
      inner_join(df)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   name          Activity         
#   <chr>         <chr>            
# 1 Tech_activity Checking emails  
# 2 Tech_activity Watching YouTube 
# 3 Tech_activity Watching TV      
# 4 Tech_activity Watching TV      
# 5 Work          Working/ studying
# 6 Leisure       Getting ready    
# 7 Leisure       Playing games    
# 8 Leisure       Reading          
# 9 Leisure       Relaxing         
#10 Leisure       Relaxing
```