# Reclassifying factor levels in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I want to reduce the levels of the categorical variable.

I have a variable for the different levels of resident's income like: '0 to 1000$','1000 to 2000',...

I want to reclassify these 26 levels to only 3 levels `c('low','medium','high')` with certain definitions.

Here is what I have tried.

```
classify<- setNames(list(c('Under $1 000','$1 000 To 2 999','$3 000 To 3 999','$4 000 To 4 999','$5 000 To 5 999','$6 000 To 6 999','$7 000 To 7 999','$8 000 To 9 999','$10000 To 12499','$12500 To 14999','$15000 To 17499','$17500 To 19999','$20000 To 22499','$22500 To 24999','$25000 To 29999','$30000 To 34999','$35000 To 39999','$40000 To 49999','$50000 To 59999'), c('$60000 To 74999','$75000 To $89999','$90000 To $109999'),c('$110000 To $129999','$130000 To $149999','$150000 Or Over')),c("low", "medium", "high"))
f<- function(x) names(classify[sapply(classify, function(y) x %in% y)])
q3$level<- as.factor(sapply(q3$income06,f))
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Comment: You can use the same approach as in these answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234685/replacing-values-of-a-dataframe-column-using-values-of-a-list-and-list-name-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(q3)
for(i in names(classify)){
  q3[value %in% unlist(classify[i]), level := i]
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.
error:
Error in `:=`(level, i) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: you have to convert the q3 to a data.table first using setDT(q3). Altered the script accordingly.